# Spring configuration method call to pass Calendar.YEAR

Tags: spring

I am trying to pass this arguments to the method call Calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10) in the Spring config. How to pass Calendar.YEAR which is actually an int, but Spring config treats it as a String and throws error.

It works if I call without Spring like:

```
from = from.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
```

Config:

```
<bean id="currCalendar"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="java.util.Calendar"/>
        <property name="staticMethod">
            <value>java.util.Calendar.getInstance</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="from1"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="currCalendar"/>
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="add"/>
        <property name="arguments">

            <list>
                  <value type="int">currCalendar.YEAR</value>
                <value type="int">-50</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Please suggest how to do in `Spring`

Comment: In fact I did try this #{} placeholder before posting. When I try and use the java code to get the bean named `code Calendar cal = (Calendar)factory.getApplicationContext().getBean("from1");  `gives Null Exception error

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, use the `#{}` placeholder:

```
<list>
      <value type="int">#{currCalendar.YEAR}</value>
      <value type="int">-50</value>
</list>
```

Comment: In fact I did try this #{} placeholder before posting. When I try and use the java code to get the bean named `code Calendar cal = (Calendar)factory.getApplicationContext().getBean("from1"); `gives Null Exception error. Looks like the bean is not initialized. Do I need to add any XML namespace reference for the placeholder.

Comment: There's no such bean named "from1". You should get currCalendar instead of from1: `Calendar cal = (Calendar)factory.getApplicationContext().getBean("currCalendar");`. Notice that the second `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` is calling an add method in currCalendar. add() returns void so you aren't creating any new bean named "from1".

Comment: So does that mean the config file needs to changed.Would you be able to suggest how the new config file will look like without the from1 bean

Comment: When I try with currCalendar, getting this error message

Comment: When I try with currCalendar, getting this error message Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'from1' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'Calendar' cannot be found on object of type